# Why my bootloader crashes when calling function in infinite loop?

Tags: bootloader, bios

My bootloader crashes in infinite loop when calling empty function I don't know why.

init.s:

```
.code16 # generate 16 bit code
.text

__start:
    call __set_protected_mode # Enable protected mode
    jmp __start32

__set_protected_mode:
mov %eax, %cr0
or %eax, 1
mov %cr0, %eax
ret

__start32:
call init
```

init2.c:

```
void main()
{

}

void init()
{
    main();
    while(1)
    {
        main(); // when I comment this line bootloader not crashes why?
    }
}
```

Is there any way to fix it? 
I'm using bochs to test, and Ubuntu 14.04
gcc version: 4.8.4

```
Log from bochs: 

00014041548i[BIOS ] Booting from 0000:7c00
00014041624e[CPU0 ] jump_protected: cs == 0
========================================================================
Event type: ERROR
Device: [CPU0 ]
Message: jump_protected: cs == 0
```